# Predicate logic - Different ways to write the same thing.

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I have to answer this question.

```
Let the domain of the following predicates be defined as P, the set of married people:
everyone in P is married to someone else in P. For any two people
a ∈ P & b ∈ P.
let M(a,b) denote that a is married (to b). You should note that a is not the same as b.
M(a,b)=( true if a is married to b, false otherwise)

Question:
Everyone in P is married to someone else in P.
```

The correct answer was this:

> ∀ y. ∃ x. M(y,x)

The answer I wrote was this:

> $∀ x. ∀ y. x \neq y \implies  M(x,y)$

To me the correct answer reads like this:

> For all y, there exists an x where y is married to x.

The way I read my answer is:

> For all x, for all y if x doesn't equal y then x is married to y.

Is my answer correct?

Comment: You wrote something to the effect that "everyone is married to everyone, except him/herself."

Comment: @amWhy If I changed the quantifier for y from For all to There Exists would that make my answer correct?

Comment: That would be the correct use of quantifiers in this case. But you also, then, need to change the major connective in the quantified statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer $$\forall x\forall y\Big((x\neq y)\to M(x, y)\Big)$$

says, essentially "Everyone is married to everyone, except to him/herself."

Yes, you should change $\forall y$ to $\exists y$, **and** you should should use "$\land$", and not "$\to$."

Then you can correctly express the proposition:

$$\forall x, \exists y\Big((x\neq y) \land M(x, y)\Big)$$